# Operator Norm Bound in Uniform Boundedness Principle Proof

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

A statement of the proof I am referring to can be found in this question: [Understanding the proof of the uniform boundedness principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097899/understanding-the-proof-of-the-uniform-boundedness-principle).

There is a small detail in the proof that is causing me some trouble. Towards the end, he states $\|Tx\| \leq 2n$ whenever $T \in A$ and $\|x\| < r$. He seems to somehow conclude from this that $\sup_{T \in A} \|T\| \leq 2n/r$.

The operator norm is defined as:
$$\|T\| = \sup \Big\{\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}: x \neq 0 \Big\}.$$

So using what we have:
$$\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} \leq \frac{2n}{\|x\|}.$$
However, we also have that $\|x\| \leq r$, so how can we necessarily conclude that $\sup_{T \in A} \|T\| \leq 2n/r$ if $r$ is necessarily larger than $\|x\|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several equivalent ways of writing the operator norm. One of them is
\begin{align}
\|T\|=\sup\left\{\|T(\xi)\|\,:\, \|\xi\|\leq 1\right\}.
\end{align}
Now, for every $T\in A$ and $\|x\|\leq r$, we have $\|T(x)\|\leq 2n$. Divide both sides by $r$ to get $\|T\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)\|\leq \frac{2n}{r}$. Now, notice that $\frac{x}{r}$ is a vector of norm at most $1$, and the vector $x$ is arbitrary, so the number $\frac{2n}{r}$ is an upper bound for the set above. Thus, by definition of supremum, we have $\|T\|\leq \frac{2n}{r}$. If you want to be more symbolic:
\begin{align}
\|T\|&:=\sup_{\|\xi\|\leq 1}\|T(\xi)\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq r}\left\|T\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)\right\|\leq \frac{2n}{r}.
\end{align}
(second equality is because it's the supremum of the same set of numbers in $[0,\infty)$). Finally, since $T\in A$ was arbitrary, we get $\sup\limits_{T\in A}\|T\|\leq \frac{2n}{r}$.

Comment: I was overlooking that $\|x/r\| \leq 1$, thank you!